# Popup the search result page in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, search, layout, view, router

I am building a simple app to learn VueJs.  The app has a single layout with a header, footer, and the main area for the content.   In the header, there is a search box.  The content section is simply a  tag allowing me to push different pages into this template.

Given the search box is in the header, users can trigger a search on any page. How can I tell the router to push the search result page into the content area when users perform a search from the app header bar?

The search result page displays a paginated list of documents matching the search criteria. I have the list of document made as a component.

Comment: You should post some code of what you did.

Comment: hi @JeffProd, I am not hitting a bug. This is more a general design question on how we can structure communication between components in VueJS app.  It doesn't fall into the Parent/Child pattern as the search result page is loaded dynamically by the router.